# py3k RC-1: "LookupError: unknown encoding: uft-8"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just installed the first release candidate of Python 3.0 and got this error after typing:

```
>>> help('modules foo')
```

```
[...]
LookupError: unknown encoding: uft-8
```

Notice that it says **uft**-8 and not **utf**-8

Is this a py3k specific bug or a misconfiguration on my part? I do not have any other versions of Python installed on this French locale Windows XP SP3 machine.

**Edit**

A [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue4135?@ok_message=msg%2074871%20created%3Cbr%3Eissue%204135%20created&@template=item) has been filled by [Alex Coventry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22899/alex-coventry) on October 16th.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a typo, it's a deliberate error in a test module.

```
met% pwd
/home/coventry/src/Python-3.0rc1
met% rgrep uft-8 .
./Lib/test/bad_coding.py:# -*- coding: uft-8 -*-
./py3k/Lib/test/bad_coding.py:# -*- coding: uft-8 -*-
```

Removing this module causes the `help` command to fall over in a different way.

It is a bug, however.  Someone should file a report.

Comment: I submitted a report.

http://bugs.python.org/issue4135?@ok_message=msg%2074871%20created%3Cbr%3Eissue%204135%20created&@template=item

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo in a config file somewhere, whether in the Py3k package or on your machine.  You might try installing the stable final Python 2.6 (which supports 3.0 syntax changes with imports from `__future__`), and if that works you should probably file a bug report.